# Switch case on Set[] in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wonder how to use switch case on set. Nothing's below is working for me. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
fruits= Set[]
fruits.add("apple")
fruits.add("lemon")

case fruits
when "apple"
  eat
when fruits.include?("lemon")
  eat_now
else
  not_eat
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fruits = Set["apple", "lemon"]

case "apple"
when fruits
  eat
else
  not_eat
end
```

More info you can find here https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D.